# Client certificate validation in combination with certificate pinning

Tags: ssl, xamarin.ios, pinning

Do i need to perform certificate pinning after i authenticated with a client certificate? Can someone explain this to me?

```
if (challenge.ProtectionSpace.AuthenticationMethod == NSUrlProtectionSpace.AuthenticationMethodClientCertificate)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Client Cert!");

    var options = NSDictionary.FromObjectAndKey(NSObject.FromObject(This._passphrase), SecImportExport.Passphrase);

    NSDictionary[] importResult;

    if (This?._certificate == null) return;
    if (This?._passphrase == null) return;

    var x509Certificate = new X509Certificate(This._certificate, This._passphrase);

    SecStatusCode statusCode = SecImportExport.ImportPkcs12(This._certificate, options, out importResult);
    var identityHandle = importResult[0][SecImportExport.Identity];
    var identity = new SecIdentity(identityHandle.Handle);
    var certificate = new SecCertificate(x509Certificate.GetRawCertData());

    SecCertificate[] certificates = { certificate };
    NSUrlCredential credential = NSUrlCredential.FromIdentityCertificatesPersistance(identity, certificates, NSUrlCredentialPersistence.ForSession);
                completionHandler(NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, credential);

    return;
}

*Logic for SSL Pinning*
```

Since there is a return statment after the "clientcertificate request and client authentication" part, the logic for certificate pinning will never be executed, so i was asking myself if this part is obsolet after performing authentication with a client certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client certificates are used to authenticate the client against the server and nothing else. Server certificates instead are used to make sure that you talk to the correct server.

A proper check for the correct server certificate can not be replaced by sending a client certificate. Otherwise a man in the middle attacker could simply ask the client for a client certificate in the hope that the client accepts the attackers faked server certificate in exchange.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. I solved the issue after 2-3 hours of searching without being able to debug... the method called DidReciveResponse is getting called twice once for the client certificate and second time for the server certificate.